# Jests tests cannot find image Webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jestjs, webpacker

I'm getting the following error in my jests tests:

```
Cannot find module 'images/skill_levels/results-low.png' from 'skillLevelType.js'
```

The images are working in development and are stored in the regular rails images directory.

My webpacker.yml file is the default configuration. The only think that I've changed is adding `resolved_paths: ['app/assets']` to the default block.

Answer (score 0):

The following resolved this issue:

1. Create a Stub.js file:

`export default {};`

2. Update jest configuration in package.json:

   "jest": {
     "roots": [
       "app/javascript"
     ],
     "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "/app/javascript/components/setupTests.js",
     "moduleNameMapper": { 
       "\.(png|jpg)$": "/app/javascript/components/Stub.js"
     }
   }